# How does miniconda gcc handle glibc name resolution?

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, glibc, miniconda

I have gcc 12.2 installed in miniconda env. In conda env there is a sysroot directory which contains `libc.so.6` which links to `libc-2.12.so`.  In my system directory there also is `/lib64/libc.so.6` which links to `libc-2.28.so`.

I know that `libc-2.12.so` does not have the versioned symbol `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14`, and this symbol does exist in `libc-2.28.so`.

I did a simple test using the following C code.

```
// main.c file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>

#ifdef USE_VERSION
__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.14");
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buf1[10];
  const char buf2[N] = "ok, good";
  memcpy(buf1, buf2, sizeof(buf1));  // N is a macro defined in command line
  printf("GNU libc version: %s\n", gnu_get_libc_version());
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

case 1: Run following command

```bash
 $GCC -DN=9 main.c
```

gives warning (`reading 10 bytes from a region of size 9`), but compiles and runs. The program prints `GNU libc version: 2.28`, which means the executable at run-time links with system libc.so.6.

case 2: If enable symbol versioning,

```bash
 $GCC -DUSE_VERSION -DN=9 main.c
```

the compiler failed with error msg `undefined reference to memcpy@GLIBC_2.14`. Since system's `libc.so.6 (v2.28)` has this symbol, but in conda env `libc.so.6 (v2.12)` does not.
So it seems to me that at compile time, the compiler uses the conda env `libc.so.6 (v2.12)`.

case 3: If I enable symbol versioning and set N to 10 or bigger.

```bash
 $GCC -DUSE_VERSION -DN=10 main.c
```

It compiles without any warning/error and runs, output is `GNU libc version: 2.28`.

So here are my questions:

1. why does conda gcc not link to conda `libc.so.6`? The compiled binary links to system `libc.so.6`.
2. From my experiments, it seems conda gcc link to system `libc.so.6` but use conda `libc.so.6` to resolve symbol names, is it true? If true, why?

Comment: What does it output in case 3?

Comment: same as case 1. GNU libc version: 2.28